# qemu-nbd not creating partions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qemu

I was using `qemu-nbd` to mount `.vdi` virtual machine harddrives. However, `qemu-nbd` suddenly* stopped working.

My usual workflow was

```
# modprobe --verbose nbd
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-127-generic/kernel/drivers/block.nbd.ko max_part=15
# qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 /path/to/vm.vdi
# mount -o loop /dev/nbd0p1 /mnt/
... do stuff to /mnt/ content ...
# umount /mnt/
# qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0
# rmmod nbd
```

This process now does not work anymore. `qemu-nbd -c ...` does not create `nbd0p1` anymore and thus it cannot be mounted.

Using `--verbose` results in `qemu-nbd` not terminating after the line

`NBD device /dev/nbd0 is now connected to /path/to/vm.vdi`

The same process used to work on the computer without fault. The same process works on a different computer without fault using the same `.vdi` (checked via `md5sum`). The computer in question runs an Ubuntu 16.04.

How can I restore the process to working order?

I tried:

- restarting the computer
- `apt-get purge qemu-utils && apt-get install qemu-utils`
- passing `max_part=16` to `modprobe` (as suggested by some online sources)

*suddenly means that I executed the script successfully and the next time no `nbd0p1` was created even though I did not install updates or made any configuration changes I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use:

```
partprobe -s /dev/nbd0
```

Comment: To make this a better answer you might consider adding an explanation of why this will fix the problem.